In vector addition, why did the efficiency not improve despite increasing the number of CUDA threads?
I tried to use CUDA to speed up vector addition.
From add<<<1, 1>>>(N, x, y); to add<<<1, 256>>>(N, x, y);, the efficiency improved greatly. 65.409ms --> 3.0164ms (use nvprof)


#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
// Kernel function to add the elements of two arrays
__global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
  int index = threadIdx.x;
  int stride = blockDim.x;
  for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
      y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

int main(void)
{
  int N = 1<<20;
  float *x, *y;

  // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
  cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&y, N*sizeof(float));

  // initialize x and y arrays on the host
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = 1.0f;
    y[i] = 2.0f;
  }

  // Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
  add<<<1, 256>>>(N, x, y);

  // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();

  // Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)
  float maxError = 0.0f;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i]-3.0f));
  std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

  // Free memory
  cudaFree(x);
  cudaFree(y);
  
  return 0;
}

However, when I took into account the entire grid of thread blocks, the efficiency did not improve.

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> // function to add the elements of two arrays


__global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
  int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
  for (int i = index; i < n; i += stride)
    y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
} 

int main(void)
{ 
  int N = 1<<20; 
  float *x, *y;
  cudaMallocManaged(&x, N * sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&y, N * sizeof(float)); 
  
  
  // initialize x and y arrays on the host 
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { x[i] = 1.0f; y[i] = 2.0f; } 


  // Run kernel on 1M elements on the CPU 
  int blockSize = 256;
  int numBlocks = (N + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
  add<<<numBlocks, blockSize>>>(N, x, y);

  // Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  
  // Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f) 
  float maxError = 0.0f; 
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i]-3.0f)); 
  std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;



  // Free memory 
  cudaFree(x);
  cudaFree(y);

  return 0;
}

Environment

Device: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
CUDA Version: 12.6
NVIDIA-SMI 560.35.03
Driver Version: 560.35.03

In this tutorial, using grid-stride loop can greatly improve speed.


the use of managed memory and associated demand-paging is preventing you from observing your expected outcome.  Proper use of cudaMemPrefetchAsync should allow you to see continued improvement going from one block to several blocks.  this  may be of interest.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Copy the CLI output in text form into a code block instead to preserve its formatting.

Note that nvprof is deprecated in favor of Nsight Compute (ncu).
